# show column filters with autocomplete in jquery datatable server data

Tags: jquery, datatables

In jquery datatable, can we bind autocomplete textbox as column filter?
my code is shown below. But it does not showing column filters.

```
oTable = $("#tblPreProcess").dataTable({
            bProcessing: true,
            bLengthChange: false,
            bFilter: true,
            sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("FetchPreprocessOrders", "Admin")',
            aoColumns: [
               { sTitle: "Order No", bSortable: false ,bSearchable: true},
                { sTitle: "Vol.Weight", bSortable: false },
                { sTitle: "Content", bSortable: false, },               
                 { sTitle: "Bag Number", bSortable: false }                               
            ]               

        });
```

any one can help me please?

Comment: Where should that autocomplete textbox come from, in the example provided? What kind of autocomplete textbox anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this bootstrap typeahead - it is pretty awesome and supports different databases - used it recently for a multiple text input from a list(and also works without one): http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/